# How to disable menu items in the ContextMenuStrip?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, contextmenustrip

I have options like "Add", "Delete" and "Update" in my ContextMenuStrip, which should pop up when the user right clicks on a ListView.

How can I make the Update menu disabled if there are no items in the list view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using the MouseDown event:

```
void listView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
  if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right) {
    updateToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = (listView1.Items.Count > 0);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Use the ContextMenuStrip.Opening event..

```
if (ListBox1.Items.Count == 0) {
     ItemAToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/74Lax.png

Comment: i asked about listview not listbox